# Polymorphism with generics?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, run-time-polymorphism

I have a class A -> class B (child of A) -> class C (child of B) and class A -> class D.
How can I write a function that return objects from class B and class D, example below.
How to implement the calling part?

The problem is If I do A a = getFunction() I cannot access the B's functions.

```
public <T> T getFunction(IntegrationType integrationType) {
      return (T) integrationFactory.createIntegration(integrationType);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "class A -> class D"? Are you saying class D is a child of A?

Comment: Maybe include more code in your example.

Comment: I may not understand what you're asking, but since A is the parent, you could do something like this:

A classB = new B();
A classD = new D();

classB.getFunction():
classD.getFunction();

Comment: @Mahesh Have a look at java Collections class - e.g `Collections.<String>emptyList()` - gives you a list where the return type is List<String>..

Comment: Have you tried `public <T extends A> getFunction...` - so then the return type is exactly what you want ...

Comment: if you want to access B's methods you'd have to use `B b = getFunction()` (with T = B, i.e. `getFunction<B>()`) which may or may not work depending on the integration factory. The code you posted doesn't look like it would work though because generics can't access child classes magically. You might need a different approach.

Comment: If you know when calling what type you are expecting back (either a B or a D), then you can add that to the call, so something like `public <T> T getFunction(IntegrationType integrationType, Class<T> clazz) `, and call by `B b = getFunction(type, B.class)`

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is If I do A a = getFunction() I cannot access the B's functions.

You can use the `instanceof` operator. For example:

```
A a = getFunction();
if (a instanceof B) {
    B b = (B) a;
    // you can call the methods of B here
}
```

Or, if you are using Java 16 or higher, you can try the pattern matching as follows:

```
A a = getFunction();
if (a instanceof B b) {
    b.someMethod();
}
```